# No stack trace for FirebaseError in vitest output

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vitest

I'm trying to set up security testing for my web app, using vitest and the firebase testing package `@firebase/rules-unit-testing`. This largely works, but unfortunately the errors look like this:

```
FAIL  tests/security.test.ts > inviting someone to an ancestor board with nested sharing
FirebaseError: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: 
evaluation error at L44:24 for 'create' @ L44, evaluation error at L45:32 for 'update' @ L45, false for 'create' @ L44
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
Serialized Error: { code: 'permission-denied', customData: undefined }
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯[1/6]⎯

 Test Files  1 failed (1)
      Tests  6 failed (6)
   Start at  13:24:40
   Duration  520ms
```

This tells me which firestore security rule was broken, but it doesn't tell me anything about which line of the test was responsible. I want it to look more like the normal output for throwing an error, which is like so:

```
FAIL  tests/security.test.ts > inviting someone to an ancestor board with nested sharing
Error: oh no
 ❯ tests/security.test.ts:239:9
    237| 
    238| test("inviting someone to an ancestor board with nested sharing", async () => {
    239|   throw new Error("oh no");
       |         ^
```

How can I get a stack trace in there?